# PHP MySQL Search Form with Multiple Categories of Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox

This seems too straightforward as first to be a problem - but here is is anyway.

Lets say you have a search form, and you're looking for companies which deal in certain branches of an industry. The form will present a set of set of checkboxes for each question, and the user may choose any amount they want.

---

**What are your favorite colors?**

[ ] Red

[ ] Blue

[ ] Yellow

**What are your favorite fruits?**

[ ] Apple

[ ] Orange

[ ] Banana

---

*Problem No.1*

If the user checks red and blue - do we pull from the database rows that match only both? Or do we include rows that also match just red or just blue? In my mind the end-user may expect to see one outcome or the other, or both!

*Problem No.2*

Baring in mind that the CMS I have to use stores data in arrays for each question. So Company A for the first question may hold values "Red|Blue" or "Red" or "Red|Blue|Yellow" etc - plus the fast that the form I have has 10 categories each with at least 5 checkboxes - how can I translate this into an efficient and optimised query without having to resort to if/else mish mash?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's very likely to be a conjunction (red or blue) not a disjunction (red and blue),, but it depends on the semantics of the question. If you give options that can co-occur, then you might need a disjunction.
2. I can't see a better way than something like

   $colours = $POST["colour[]"];
   $items = array();

   foreach ($colours as $colour) {

   $items[] = "'$colour' IN colours";

   }

   $SQL .= "AND (".implode(' OR ', $items).")";

Answer (score 0):

For P2, I would make a table "many-to-many", and would use a query with IN statement.
For P1,something like
ex: red,blue,white

```
select id,color,count(color) as occurrences from table inner join table_attributes where color in ('red','blue','white') order by occurrences
```

based on the number of occurrences you can sort the results